# Help to drawing a plot in latex: A circular node with 8 arrows coming in

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]
Hi,
I want to draw the following figure. Could anyone help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe you could indicate what you tried and where you got stuck, so you aren't asking other people to do it all for you.

Comment: I almost did nothing. I know how to draw the block diagram, but about the above figure, I don't have any clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here another example to get you started. It uses `\foreach` to make things compact.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mycirclestyle/.style={draw,fill=blue!50,circle, minimum size=1cm,inner sep=2pt},
myarrowstyle/.style={stealth-,
    line width=1.5mm,
    draw=green!50,}
]
\node[mycirclestyle,name=circle] at (0,0) {A};
\foreach \direction/\angle/\anchordir/\ttext in {north/90/south/2, north east/45/south west/1, east/0/west/2, south east/-45/north west/4, south/-90/north/8, south west/-135/north east/5, west/-180/east/4, north west/135/south east/3}
{\draw[myarrowstyle](circle.\direction)--++(\angle:1cm)node[anchor=\anchordir]{\ttext};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of circular node in center with radial arrows coming in]

Some modifications as requested in comments:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mycirclestyle/.style={draw,fill=blue!50,circle, minimum size=1cm,inner sep=2pt},
myarrowstyle/.style={stealth-,
    line width=1.5mm,
    draw=green!50,}
]
\node[mycirclestyle,name=circle] at (0,0) {A};
\foreach \direction/\angle/\anchordir/\ttext in {
north/90/south/Very very smart\\ \& efficient, 
north east/45/south west/dumb and\\ \& boring, 
east/0/west/2, 
south east/-45/north west/4, 
south/-90/north/8, 
south west/-135/north east/5, 
west/-180/east/4, 
north west/135/south east/3
}
{\draw[myarrowstyle](circle.\direction)--++(\angle:1cm)node[anchor=\anchordir,align=center,font=\tiny]{\ttext};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of circular node in center with radial arrows coming in]

Comment: If you care for more explanation, please let me know.

Comment: My sincere compliments.

Comment: Thank you so much. The only thing is that, I want to add some text instead of number, I want to put for example (Very very smart and efficient). I have to change the font of the text, and also I have to put them in two lines. Could you help me with that? thank you so much

Comment: Made some modifications.

Answer (score 2):

For exercises ... As starting point is used [@Matthias Arras answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565392/help-to-drawing-a-plot-in-latex-a-circular-node-with-8-arrows-coming-in/565397#565397):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
A/.style = {{Triangle[angle=90:1pt 1.5]}-, line width=2mm, 
            draw=green!50, shorten <=1pt},
C/.style = {draw,fill=blue!50,circle, minimum size=1cm,inner sep=2pt},
every label/.append style = {label distance=0pt, inner sep=0pt, align=center,
                             font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
]
\node (c) [C] {A};
\foreach \angle/\j in {45/{some\\ text},
                        90/{very smart\\\& efficient},
                        135/{dump and\\boring},
                        180/4, 225/5, 270/6,315/7,360/8}
{
\draw[A](c.\angle) --++ (\angle:1) node[coordinate,label=\angle:\j] {};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this `(c.\angle)` way more elegant than the verbose `north` etc.

Comment: @MatthiasArras, thank you! However,  as wee can see, your answer better fit OP's  expectation as mine :-)

Comment: Ah...I have not seen your answer....:-(

Comment: @Sebastiano, ah it is small (variation of accepted)  and it is on end of line ...

Answer (score 1):

I have used the usual [tool](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) (Mathcha) on line to be more fast to create a MWE code that use `TikZ` and because the OP have not a MWE but only a picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,449); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 449

%Shape: Circle [id:dp1982171778978865] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (180,196.5) .. controls (180,140.44) and (225.44,95) .. (281.5,95) .. controls (337.56,95) and (383,140.44) .. (383,196.5) .. controls (383,252.56) and (337.56,298) .. (281.5,298) .. controls (225.44,298) and (180,252.56) .. (180,196.5) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp22122225988507926] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (261,88) -- (271.25,88) -- (271.25,38.42) -- (291.75,38.42) -- (291.75,88) -- (302,88) -- (281.5,95) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp7062817162916983] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (338.86,104.99) -- (347.11,111.07) -- (376.49,71.13) -- (393.01,83.28) -- (363.63,123.21) -- (371.88,129.29) -- (351.22,122.78) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp3683769912443131] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (390.25,176.09) -- (390.13,186.34) -- (439.7,186.95) -- (439.45,207.45) -- (389.87,206.84) -- (389.75,217.09) -- (383,196.5) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp494052891579823] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (188.7,132.9) -- (196.45,126.19) -- (164.01,88.69) -- (179.52,75.28) -- (211.95,112.78) -- (219.7,106.07) -- (208.78,124.78) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp9329955759097572] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (173.03,217.01) -- (173.01,206.76) -- (123.43,206.82) -- (123.41,186.32) -- (172.99,186.26) -- (172.97,176.01) -- (180,196.5) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp2970611155152425] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (215.58,287.43) -- (209,279.57) -- (171,311.42) -- (157.83,295.71) -- (195.83,263.86) -- (189.25,256.01) -- (207.78,267.22) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp9615345014605625] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (301.95,305.14) -- (291.7,305.07) -- (291.35,354.65) -- (270.86,354.51) -- (271.2,304.93) -- (260.95,304.86) -- (281.5,298) -- cycle ;
%Down Arrow [id:dp4938034366309434] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (370.93,260.77) -- (363.89,268.21) -- (399.89,302.29) -- (385.8,317.18) -- (349.79,283.1) -- (342.75,290.54) -- (351.76,270.84) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp8305861515615227] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (256.5,171.5) -- (306.5,171.5) -- (306.5,221.5) -- (256.5,221.5) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (282.05,193.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$A$};
% Text Node
\draw (395.05,59.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (282.05,18.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$2$};
% Text Node
\draw (164.05,65.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$3$};
% Text Node
\draw (107.05,193.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$4$};
% Text Node
\draw (150.05,308.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$5$};
% Text Node
\draw (281.05,371.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$6$};
% Text Node
\draw (406.05,321.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$7$};
% Text Node
\draw (457.05,195.5) node  [font=\LARGE]  {$8$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is amazing tool. But I try to learn work with that, its a little difficult for me. In that website you only upload the figure and change the figure to the latex code?

Comment: @Esskand I cite this tool for the newbie in LaTeX/TikZ without a MWE. It is not difficult to understand. You drawing and export in TikZ. Take the code and paste in a MWE. :-). All the best.